# Simpson Rule with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my numerical course I have to use simpsons rule to approximate the integral of three different function which are listed below.... My code runs but it isn't giving me the correct approximation and I don't know why....

```
import math
def F(x):
    c = x * math.log(x)
    return c
def G(x):
    g = 2 / (x**2 + 4)
    return g
def H(x):
    h = x**2 * math.cos(x)
    return h
def simpsonRule(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    k = 0
    z = 0
    for i in range(1, (n//2) - 1):
        k += 2*f(a+(2*i*h))

    for i in range(1, (n//2)):
        z += 4*f(a+((2*i)-1)*h)    
    return (h*(f(a) + k + z + f(b))) / 3


AA = simpsonRule(F, 1, 2, 4)
CC = simpsonRule(G, 0, 2, 6)
DD = simpsonRule(H, 0, math.pi, 6)

print(AA)
print(CC)
print(DD)
```

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables in different places and compare it with calculations on paper.

Comment: I see three possible problems: (1) code is not correct - it doesn't use algoryth correctly. (2) `math.cos()` expects radius but you use degrees (3) float in computer can't keep all possible values so it keeps aproximation and then result can't be ideal. ie. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` gives `False`

Comment: Can you share the expected output for the inputs too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the upper limit of your `range()` calls is off by 1.  The upper limit is never reached so it should be one beyond what you want.  I've included an extra test case, `sin(x)`, for which I knew the right answer (~1):

```
import math

def E(x):
    return math.sin(x)

def F(x):
    return x * math.log(x)

def G(x):
    return 2 / (x**2 + 4)

def H(x):
    return x**2 * math.cos(x)

def simpsonRule(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / n
    k = 0
    z = 0

    for i in range(1, n // 2):
        k += 2 * f(a + 2 * i * h)

    for i in range(1, n // 2 + 1):
        z += 4 * f(a + (2 * i - 1) * h)

    return h * (f(a) + k + z + f(b)) / 3.0

AA = simpsonRule(F, 1, 2, 4)
CC = simpsonRule(G, 0, 2, 6)
DD = simpsonRule(H, 0, math.pi, 6)
EE = simpsonRule(E, 0, math.pi / 2, 100)

print(AA)
print(CC)
print(DD)
print(EE)
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
0.6363098297969493
0.7853979452340107
-6.274868388453119
1.0000000003382359
>
```

Comment: The output is correct with what I have done by hand. Thanks but I'm still confused on why you changed the for loops the way you did... if you look at the algorithm the 1 to 1/n - 1 limit has the function multiplied by 2 but you multiplied it by 4 and reversed the other one as well... I just dont get why

Comment: @JozyMan, I don't know what you're asking.  My code is *identical* to your posted code except for the upper limit of the `range()` calls is 1 greater and I removed unnecessary parens.  I don't see any 2 vs. 4 change nor reversal.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are using Python 2.x, the problem may be caused by the types of variables. All variables in the right-hand side of the expersion `h = (b-a)/n` are `int`, therefore the interpreter assumes that `h` must be `int` as well. The problem can be solved by the type conversion

```
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
```

inserted before that expression.

The mentioned above behavior is specific to Python 2 and it has been fixed in Python 3 assuming `float` in this situation. See [here](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/interesting-casting-in-python) more examples with the type casting in Python.

The output without conversion:

```
0.0
0
-1.36541969235
```

The output with conversion:

```
0.208501009808
0.577327327327
-1.36541969235
```

Comment: `h` would only be an int on Python 2. The questioner says they're on Python 3. While they could be wrong about that, posting a Python 2-specific answer without investigating the version first seems premature.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the answer pointing out that it is applicable for Python 2

Comment: In the question, there are two tags, one is general python question, and another is Python 3- specific one. So I have decided the question is not restricted to Python 3 only.

Comment: First, the `python` tag was edited in by another user. Second, Python 3-specific questions are supposed to be tagged both `python` and `python-3.x`. Version-agnostic questions are supposed to not have a `python-3.x` tag. Third, why would the `python-3.x` tag even be there if the questioner was running (or believed they were running) Python 2?

Comment: Is this a kind of apriori knowledge or it is written somewhere about both tags? How am I supposed to know what is added by another user? Someone could add both tags if he is not sure.

Comment: There's an edit history, visible by clicking the "edited 27 mins ago" text on the post.

Comment: Am I supposed to read the edit history each time i answer a question?